# Tomcat Deployment automation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, deployment, eclipse-plugin

I am using the eclipse indigo and tomcat 6. 
I have two projects, one for web contents (XML, HTML, JSP, JS) and one for application layer (Java classes). 
I linked the web project using the "deployment assembly" and "project preferences" in eclipse.
However, whenever I change a java file in the application project, and restart the server it doesn't deploy in tomcat. 
Every time, I should clean the tomcat, build the project and  run the tomcat to see the changes.
Can you tell me a plugin, add-on or a trick that I could automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does this for you. Turn on Project / Build Automatically, then in the Tomcat Overview (double click on the server in the Server View), under Publishing, select Automatically publish when resources change, and set the Publishing interval to some low number.

Comment: I used the same configuration, but it needs cleaning each time!

Comment: So the answer is probably that your eclipse metadata is messed up. Try removing your Tomcat server, then restarting Eclipse with the -clean parameter, then adding the Tomcat server back. This should clean up any data related to that server.